# Upload app to TestFlight/App Store when on macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 beta

Tags: macos-high-sierra

I upgraded to macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 beta by mistake, and now I'm wondering if I have to downgrade to the latest High Sierra version to upload my app to TestFlight/App Store.

Comment: Are you getting a particular error when you try?

Comment: No, I wanted to ask before I either tried to upload or downgraded if I didn't have to. But I sorted it out!